Twillio - A function that will send an automatic response to incoming messages, and also mimic behavior of webhook integration?
Is it possible to write a function for incoming SMS messages that will both route the incoming message via webhook in the same manner as the integration configuration on a messaging service - and also send a pre-written response/disclaimer?
Previously we had been able to do this (possibly an oversight/bug that it ever worked) by configuring an auto-response flow on the "a message comes in" portion of the phone number configuration, while configuring the URL for our case management service integration section of the service configuration
Integration configuration:

Flow:

Basically - is there a way to reliably do both of these actions for all incoming messages?
I tried modifying this function
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('querystring');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

  let {
    ApiVersion,
    SmsSid,
    SmsStatus,
    SmsMessageSid,
    NumSegments,
    ToState,
    From,
    MessageSid,
    AccountSid,
    ToCity,
    FromCountry,
    ToZip,
    FromCity,
    To,
    FromZip,
    ToCountry,
    Body,
    NumMedia,
    FromState
  } = event;

  let requestBody = {
    ApiVersion,
    SmsSid,
    SmsStatus,
    SmsMessageSid,
    NumSegments,
    ToState,
    From,
    MessageSid,
    AccountSid,
    ToCity,
    FromCountry,
    ToZip,
    FromCity,
    To,
    FromZip,
    ToCountry,
    Body,
    NumMedia,
    FromState
  };

  let url1 = "https://example.com/1";
  let url2 = "https://example.com/2";

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };

  Promise.all([
    axios.post(url1, qs.stringify(requestBody), config),
    axios.post(url2, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
  ]).then(result => {
    callback(null, twiml);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
  });
};

To use "get" rather than "post (as required by our case management software's Twilio integration) but simply replacing "post" with "get" but that didn't work (did not expect it would really.)
Is it possible to do this entirely with a Twilio flow by including elements in the request body like:

EDIT: This worked!
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('querystring');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

  let {
    ApiVersion,
    SmsSid,
    SmsStatus,
    SmsMessageSid,
    NumSegments,
    ToState,
    From,
    MessageSid,
    AccountSid,
    ToCity,
    FromCountry,
    ToZip,
    FromCity,
    To,
    FromZip,
    ToCountry,
    Body,
    NumMedia,
    FromState
  } = event;

  let requestBody = {
    ApiVersion,
    SmsSid,
    SmsStatus,
    SmsMessageSid,
    NumSegments,
    ToState,
    From,
    MessageSid,
    AccountSid,
    ToCity,
    FromCountry,
    ToZip,
    FromCity,
    To,
    FromZip,
    ToCountry,
    Body,
    NumMedia,
    FromState
  };

  let url1 = https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID/Flows/FLOW_SID;
  let url2 = https://lanc.legalserver.org/modules/sms/processor.php;

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(context.ACCOUNT_SID + ':' + context.AUTH_TOKEN).toString('base64')
    }
  };

  axios.post(url2, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
    .then(response1 => {
      console.log("Response from url2:", response1.data);
      // Forward to Twilio Flow
      axios.post(url1, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
        .then(response2 => {
          console.log("Response from url1:", response2.data);
          callback(null, twiml);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Error from url1:", err);
          callback(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error from url2:", err);
      callback(err);
    });
};


Yes, there are multiple ways to achieve this. One is, to use only Twilio Studio. Keep in mind, that you shouldn't return TwiML back to Studio. But you can return any response and the use that payload within a "Send Message" widget.
